# How can I make an armature and its parts a single asset?

Tags: asset-browser

I have a model composed of multiple different objects, which are parented to the bones of a single armature. It works great for my purposes, but I would like to use the new asset browser to import it into new projects. I just want it to work as if I had selected these things and CTRL+C, CTRL+V'd them.

I tried marking the armature as an asset, but that only includes the armature itself, none of the objects parented to its bones. I tried selecting the armature and all the objects and clicking "Mark Asset", but that made the armature and each object into separate assets.

How can I make the entire model---armature, bones, objects, material---into a single asset that I can easily drag and drop into other projects?

Comment: I think you're the fourth person to ask this. The answer is that you currently can't.  There is currently no way to group objects as a single asset.  Perhaps in 3.1

Answer (score 0):

In v3.4 group everything in a Collection, then mark the collection as an asset. When you pull in from the Asset Browser, make sure to select "Link" as the type from the dropdown. Drag it in. Then right click on the collection in the outliner (with the chain icon) and in the popup menu go to Library Override > Make > Selected. Now you can animate!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvRcND4zNY4

Answer (score -1):

(1) From outliner, "instance to scene" collection -> collection instance created

(2) "Mark as asset" that instance

Comment: This gives you an non-editable, non-posable object which is not the ctrl+c, ctrl+v behavior the question asked for.